# Adjust Scroll bar width in visual studio community edition 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, scrollbar

Can someone shed light on how I can adjust the width of the scroll bars in Visual Studio.  I mean the actual IDE itself and not code to do this in an application.
I have already adjusted the width of the windows explorer scroll bars (Windows 10) but this has no effect in the VS IDE.
Thanks in advance
Tony
[An image of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJZpu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the map view for vertical scrollbar in all languages settings. But it's scroll pace is different depending whether the current block is folded or not which is a little uncomfortable to use. So the quickest and smartest way in my opinion is to use the RockMargin extension. Works exactly like Sublime or VS Code minimap.